# I have been banned from asking question from mathematics stack exchange from two month what should I do now?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

When I was banned, my reputation was less than 50, and now it is greater than 100.

It means I have improved.  Also I am a beginner in abstract mathematics, so I should be given at least one more chance.

I edited my questions, and I have all questions with positive votes.  Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: Please consider the fixes I made to the above post, and use care to avoid misspelling and give correct capitalization, etc.

Comment: Links to some basic information about such bans can be found in the [post-ban tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info).

Answer (score 7):

This is an automated block. Moderators cannot change or remove this block.

The best resource to read concerning the block is the primary [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions from this account"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) post. This will describe the actions available to you as well.

A good start would be to make sure that all posts you give from now on are well-formatted. Using proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation is a good start.

---

It may also be good for you to remember all the questions you have asked. In your post, you mention that you have only questions with positive votes. But the block takes into consideration closed and deleted questions as well. In total, you have asked 10 questions. Six of them are closed and deleted. Your current net question vote total is $-5$.